# iOS - Https POST with Forms Still Recognised As JSON Content-Type

Tags: ios, post, https

I am using the following code to perform an https POST with parameters of content type, form.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", URL_IHEARTRADIO_API, URL_USER_LOGIN]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSError *error;

NSString *dataString = @"key1=value1&key2=value2";    
NSData *data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

[request setValue:[@([dataString length]) stringValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:dataString];

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[connection start];
```

However, I always get the response from server with error code 400. Plus, it also states that the content-type is application/json even if I am setting it as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

This is the response from server:

```
status code: 400, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "X-hostName, X-User-Id, X-Session-Id, Content-Type";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 23 Jun 2016 16:48:11 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding, X-hostName, X-Accept";
    Via = "1.1 varnish";
    "X-Cache" = MISS;
    "X-Cache-Hits" = 0;
    "X-Served-By" = "cache-sjc3643-SJC";
    "X-Timer" = "S1466700491.006144,VS0,VE75";
}
```

Comment: can you show the web service code

Comment: @Shubhank I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";` is the response content-type not the request.

You should check the JSON response as to why you get a 400 error.

Comment: I see, Thanks for that.